# How to setup the new analytics.js in my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have the new analitycs.js in my website´s banners, but the analytics tool won´t display the data. I try including this code

```
    <script>
    // este es analytics.js
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
    {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

and at each banner I put this tag:

```
    onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'banner', 'clic', 'lol - home_right');"
```

In my google "real time" analytics view I can see when I make a click to the banner. But when I go to:

Reports:
Behavior > Site´s Content > All pages

I can´t see the clicks I made.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours for data to show up outside of the "real time" view.  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009683?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, I set up this last week, more than 8 days ago...

Comment: Install GA Debugger and see if your hits are going through.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending events not page views. So instead of:

> Reports: Behavior > Site´s Content > All pages

Go to:

> Reports: Behavior > Events

Section and you should see the events there.